# How can I make separate sentences or paragraphs?

Tags: discussion, support, comment, markdown, formatting

Hello I am new to Stackexchange and I'm trying to learn how to make separate sentences, paragraphs and to write proper math script.

So, everytime I try to make a paragraph or separate 2 sentences using the SHIFT+ENTER buttons in a comment, it doesn't seem to work! The sentences are still side by side... I want them to be one bellow the other! How should I do it? :P

Comment: If you really want to make paragraphs, type four dollar signs with a space in the middle.  $$ $$ for example.  The space is rather large though

Comment: I think this is really a question for meta - but to try an answer: I don't think comments are (usually) the right place for multiparagraph entries, so the inability (or difficulty) doing this isn't often a problem.You can do this in questions, as your question shows. Mathjax for mathematics does work in comments, but (probably) not displayed equations.

Comment: It is not possible to put a new line in comment see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16521/how-to-go-to-the-next-line-in-comments). Comments support only a subset of formatting available in post, see [editing help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Thank you guys! Yes, I just figured out the difference between a comment and a new Question or an Answer, so it is only logical that it might not support that functionality... If it should or if it shouldn't it's a whole new discussion on its own, where I will support that it could to make the math on the page a little more easy on the eyes if you are about to write some. But one can simply do this $$x=4+2x$$ $$x=-4$$ $$:P$$

Answer (score 6):

Line-breaks and paragraphs in comments are not supported. The shift-enter is intended only to affect the situation while you edit.

It is possible to work around this restriction via using MathJax. But doinng so is discouraged. If you need some visual separation, use some symbols for example // like this:

> This is one important remark I want to make and this will take up a couple of lines. Maybe two or maybe three. It is really interesting and deserves to be elaborated on. // This is another important remark that is unrelated.  It is really interesting and deserves to be elaborated on.

Also, posting two comments instead of one, can be a good option. Especially when the two ideas are quite unrelated.

For posts (question and answer) this is different:

- You can start a new paragraph by leaving at least one line blank. Leaving more than one has no additional effect though.
- You can start a new line by leaving at least two spaces at the end of a line. Like this.
  Here a new line.
  And another.

Comment: Nice... So, can I use MathJax to separate sentences in the comments? Or can I just type what I want there instead and then post the link in as a comment?

Comment: You could, $$ \ $$ but really you should not.  $$ \ $$ It is bad to do this.  See. $$ \ $$ It is $$ \ $$ $$ \Huge \textsf{annoying.}$$ $$ \ $$ Isn't it?  $$ \ $$ If you really must, an easy way is to post a basically empty displayed formula like  `$$ \ $$` But really don't. Even if not overdone like here the spacing is just not good and it causes various issues. I do not understand the link and "there" remark. MathJax is a markup language. You use it here. But yes one can post links. But to post a link to a comment  hosted elsewhere is  not a good idea to say the least.

Comment: Yes it's really annoying! Yea the double dollar trick is nice if used with caution; Yes, I too believe that posting links is also frustrating...